# Drupal 7, Get PDO Connection Handle?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

Drupal 7 seems to be doing a very good job at hiding most of the database layer away.

All I want is the connection handle so I can do some sql without going through db_query for testing and to hand off to a reporting client so it doesn't open a new connection.

Can anyone tell me how to get a hold of the PDO connection from drupal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Database::getConnection()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/Database%3a%3agetConnection/7) should give you a driver specific implementation of [DatabaseConnection](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/class/DatabaseConnection/7). While it does override several of the methods, it should work pretty similar to a default PDO instance.

Comment: Seems I was making it harder than it was @Mickey-P:

`$db = Doctrine_Manager::connection(Database::getConnection(),
                                  $connInfo['default']['database']);`